# Dotnetnuke browser back button redirect to custom page

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke

On browser back button click i want to redirect to a Custom Page that i create,

Example: In most banking applications while transacting if you click browser back button you get Page expired page and from there you can provide some links to login again.

the below code only prevents form navigating to previous page

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function disableBackButton() {
    window.history.forward();

}
setTimeout("disableBackButton()", 0);
```

I am using DotNetNuke, could you provide any solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include that in a custom Module on every page of your website, or you could embed your JS into the SKIN for your website in DNN.